# Shortcode showing in page builder but breaks front end

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, shortcode, elementor

I'm using elementor, a page builder for Wordpress and I've created a short code to display a custom post type loop inside of it...

When I insert the shortcode, it shows up correctly in the editor but when I save it and try and visit the page normally, the code seems to have broken the page and the page just keeps repeating forever... Here's the page link: http://webserver-meetandengage-com.m11e.net/about-us/ it take a little while to load but you will see it all repeating...

I'm thinking I might not have closed the loop properly or something, but I cant see where I'm going wrong! It's also worth noting the loop works fine when added directly into a template file.

The loop is here:

```
<div class="container team-members-container">

    <h2 style="font-weight: bold; text-align: center; margin:70px 0 70px 0;">The Team</h2>

    <div class="row">

        <?php
            $args = array( 
              'post_type' => 'team_members'
              // 'orderby' => 'none'
            );
            $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
        ?>

        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

        <div class="col-sm-4">  
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">

            <?php 

            $image = get_field('photo');

            if( !empty($image) ): ?>

                <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />

            <?php endif; ?>

            <h2 class="team-name"><?php the_field('name'); ?></h2>
            <p class="team-position"><?php the_field('position'); ?></p>

        </a>
        </div>

        <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); endif; ?>

    </div>

</div>
```

and the loop is contained in its own file called team.php. The code in the functions.php file I'm using to create the shortcode is:

```
function get_team($atts) {
  ob_start();
  get_template_part('inc/team');
  return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode('team', 'get_team');
```

Creating the shortcode `[team]` to use in my page editor.

Can anyone see where the problem might be? Thanks for looking :)

Comment: did you try in visual mode or text mode in editor?

Comment: Hi vel, Im editing in visual mode for the editor where I can drag and drop blocks... I hate working with page builders but it was a client requirement unfortunately! :)

Comment: I use Sublime text also if that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 <div class="row">

        <?php
            $args = array( 
              'post_type' => 'post'
              // 'orderby' => 'none'
            );
            $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
        ?>

        <?php if ( $the_query->have_posts()  ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

        <div class="col-sm-4">  
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">

            <?php 

            $image = get_field('photo');            
            if( !empty($image) ): ?>

                <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />

            <?php endif; ?>

            <h2 class="team-name"><?php //the_field('name'); ?></h2>
            <p class="team-position"><?php //the_field('position'); ?></p>

        </a>
        </div>

        <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); endif; ?>

    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: just $the_query-> ?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing `if ( have_posts() )` to `if ( $the_query->have_posts() )`

The conditional needs to access the $the_query object properly.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query